# Stick bunch of images to each other on html

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have 7 images aligned, however there is a small space between every image. I keep trying to get rid of this space but then the images start to overlap. Each image is in a div.

html

```
<div class="row wrapper">
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.firstDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.secondDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.thirdDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.forthDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.fifthDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.sixthDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.seventhDisplay.src}}" alt="?"></div>
        </div>
```

css

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

I tried using float and margin: 0 but nothing would work. Any suggestions would help. Also, is it possible to put an icon in place of the alt? I am currently using ionic for this.

Comment: Is your intent to get each image aligned horizontally next to one another or vertically without any space?

Comment: display:block together with float:left on the images will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding:0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
     max-width: 100%;
     padding:0;

}
```

you should use chrome's or firefox's  developer tools to inspect your code.
they are very help full

Answer (score 1):

Try `font-size: 0` on `.wrapper`

It will eliminate the space after each inline-block that is due to some font issues problem it's always had.

Reset the font-size on the children if you are including text.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
   font-size: 0;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
 }

img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row wrapper">
          <div class="col container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rYqCOO2.png?2" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VNLbhsV.png?1" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/5hQOv35.png?1" alt="?"></div>
          <div class="col container"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ozNSHXi.png?1" alt="?"></div>
  </div>
```

If you want to get rid of some html code you could possibly do this..

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .wrapper {

       font-size: 0;
    }

    .container {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="row wrapper">
    <img class="col container" src="http://i.imgur.com/rYqCOO2.png?2" alt="?">
    <img class="col container" src="http://i.imgur.com/VNLbhsV.png?1" alt="?">
    <img class="col container" src="http://i.imgur.com/5hQOv35.png?1" alt="?">
    <img class="col container" src="http://i.imgur.com/ozNSHXi.png?1" alt="?">
</div>
```